# Json to DataFrame (Coinmarket cap API)

Tags: python, dataframe, api, coinmarketcap

I have a json output from CoinMarketCap API, I want to know how can I convert it to DataFrame?
{'data': {'1027': {'circulating_supply': 119359483.749,
'cmc_rank': 2,
'date_added': '2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z',
'id': 1027,
'is_active': 1,
'is_fiat': 0,
'last_updated': '2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z',
'max_supply': None,
'name': 'Ethereum',
'num_market_pairs': 5482,
'platform': None,
'quote': {'USD': {'fully_diluted_market_cap': 307402654581.68,
'last_updated': '2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z',
'market_cap': 307402654581.679,
'market_cap_dominance': 17.8235,
'percent_change_1h': 1.06045615,
'percent_change_24h': 8.70029864,
'percent_change_30d': -31.11373609,
'percent_change_60d': -44.18789242,
'percent_change_7d': 4.3122346,
'percent_change_90d': -38.78235831,
'price': 2575.435524068731,
'volume_24h': 12753359871.597496,
'volume_change_24h': -18.1848}},
'self_reported_circulating_supply': None,
'self_reported_market_cap': None,
'slug': 'ethereum',
'symbol': 'ETH',
'tags': ['mineable',
'pow',
'smart-contracts',
'ethereum-ecosystem',
'binance-smart-chain',
'coinbase-ventures-portfolio',
'three-arrows-capital-portfolio',
'polychain-capital-portfolio',
'binance-labs-portfolio',
'blockchain-capital-portfolio',
'boostvc-portfolio',
'cms-holdings-portfolio',
'dcg-portfolio',
'dragonfly-capital-portfolio',
'electric-capital-portfolio',
'fabric-ventures-portfolio',
'framework-ventures-portfolio',
'hashkey-capital-portfolio',
'kenetic-capital-portfolio',
'huobi-capital-portfolio',
'alameda-research-portfolio',
'a16z-portfolio',
'1confirmation-portfolio',
'winklevoss-capital-portfolio',
'usv-portfolio',
'placeholder-ventures-portfolio',
'pantera-capital-portfolio',
'multicoin-capital-portfolio',
'paradigm-portfolio'],
'total_supply': 119359483.749}},
'status': {'credit_count': 1,
'elapsed': 47,
'error_code': 0,
'error_message': None,
'notice': None,
'timestamp': '2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z'}}

Comment: please format your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

This is your data:

```
data = {'data': {'1027': {'circulating_supply': 119359483.749, 'cmc_rank': 2, 'date_added': '2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'id': 1027, 'is_active': 1, 'is_fiat': 0, 'last_updated': '2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z', 'max_supply': None, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'num_market_pairs': 5482, 'platform': None, 'quote': {'USD': {'fully_diluted_market_cap': 307402654581.68, 'last_updated': '2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z', 'market_cap': 307402654581.679, 'market_cap_dominance': 17.8235, 'percent_change_1h': 1.06045615, 'percent_change_24h': 8.70029864, 'percent_change_30d': -31.11373609, 'percent_change_60d': -44.18789242, 'percent_change_7d': 4.3122346, 'percent_change_90d': -38.78235831, 'price': 2575.435524068731, 'volume_24h': 12753359871.597496, 'volume_change_24h': -18.1848}}, 'self_reported_circulating_supply': None, 'self_reported_market_cap': None, 'slug': 'ethereum', 'symbol': 'ETH', 'tags': ['mineable', 'pow', 'smart-contracts', 'ethereum-ecosystem', 'binance-smart-chain', 'coinbase-ventures-portfolio', 'three-arrows-capital-portfolio', 'polychain-capital-portfolio', 'binance-labs-portfolio', 'blockchain-capital-portfolio', 'boostvc-portfolio', 'cms-holdings-portfolio', 'dcg-portfolio', 'dragonfly-capital-portfolio', 'electric-capital-portfolio', 'fabric-ventures-portfolio', 'framework-ventures-portfolio', 'hashkey-capital-portfolio', 'kenetic-capital-portfolio', 'huobi-capital-portfolio', 'alameda-research-portfolio', 'a16z-portfolio', '1confirmation-portfolio', 'winklevoss-capital-portfolio', 'usv-portfolio', 'placeholder-ventures-portfolio', 'pantera-capital-portfolio', 'multicoin-capital-portfolio', 'paradigm-portfolio'], 'total_supply': 119359483.749}}, 'status': {'credit_count': 1, 'elapsed': 47, 'error_code': 0, 'error_message': None, 'notice': None, 'timestamp': '2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z'}}
```

Define the following function that unnests any `json`:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

and do the following:

```
results = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

outdf = flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which gives:

```
 index  data.1027.circulating_supply  data.1027.cmc_rank  \
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   
0      0                  1.193595e+08                   2   

       data.1027.date_added  data.1027.id  data.1027.is_active  \
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   
0  2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z          1027                    1   

   data.1027.is_fiat    data.1027.last_updated data.1027.max_supply  \
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   
0                  0  2022-01-29T12:48:00.000Z                 None   

  data.1027.name  ...  data.1027.slug data.1027.symbol  \
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   
0       Ethereum  ...        ethereum              ETH   

   data.1027.total_supply status.credit_count  status.elapsed  \
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   
0            1.193595e+08                   1              47   

   status.error_code  status.error_message  status.notice  \
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   
0                  0                  None           None   

           status.timestamp                  data.1027.tags  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                        mineable  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                             pow  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                 smart-contracts  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z              ethereum-ecosystem  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z             binance-smart-chain  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z     coinbase-ventures-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z  three-arrows-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z     polychain-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z          binance-labs-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z    blockchain-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z               boostvc-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z          cms-holdings-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                   dcg-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z     dragonfly-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z      electric-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z       fabric-ventures-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z    framework-ventures-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z       hashkey-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z       kenetic-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z         huobi-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z      alameda-research-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                  a16z-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z         1confirmation-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z    winklevoss-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z                   usv-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z  placeholder-ventures-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z       pantera-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z     multicoin-capital-portfolio  
0  2022-01-29T12:49:23.283Z              paradigm-portfolio  

[29 rows x 37 columns]
```

Comment: Don't forgot to tick the answer to accepted if this is what you wanted. This way it won't be listed as unanswered.